# Is there a function in R allowing me to normalise my data and predict diameter at a set dose?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioinformatics

I'm analysing some data we have taken from some Kirby-bauer disk diffusion assays conducted at uni, however I feel it makes it difficult to compare the results when each of my antibiotics was tested at different doses, is there a method in R of normalising (not sure this is the correct term, my stats knowledge isn't great) the data so predicting what the diameter would be of each at say 10ug? please correct me If you believe this rational to be wrong?

data:

```
structure(list(plate = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), bacteria = c("E. coli", "E. coli", "E. coli", "E. coli", "E. coli", "E. coli", "E. coli", "E. coli", "E. coli", "E. coli", "E. coli", "E. coli", "E. coli", "E. coli", "E. coli", "S. aureus", "S. aureus", "S. aureus", "S. aureus", "S. aureus", "S. aureus", "S. aureus", "S. aureus", "S. aureus", "S. aureus", "S. aureus", "S. aureus", "S. aureus", "S. aureus", "S. aureus" ), antibiotic = c("Antibiotic X (10 μg)", "Antibiotic X (10 μg)", "Antibiotic X (10 μg)", "Penicillin (1 IU)", "Penicillin (1 IU)", "Penicillin (1 IU)", "Tetracycline (30 μg)", "Tetracycline (30 μg)", "Tetracycline (30 μg)", "Streptomycin (25 μg)", "Streptomycin (25 μg)", "Streptomycin (25 μg)", "Ampicillin (10 μg)", "Ampicillin (10 μg)", "Ampicillin (10 μg)", "Antibiotic X (10 μg)", "Antibiotic X (10 μg)", "Antibiotic X (10 μg)", "Penicillin (1 IU)", "Penicillin (1 IU)", "Penicillin (1 IU)", "Tetracycline (30 μg)", "Tetracycline (30 μg)", "Tetracycline (30 μg)", "Streptomycin (25 μg)", "Streptomycin (25 μg)", "Streptomycin (25 μg)", "Ampicillin (10 μg)", "Ampicillin (10 μg)", "Ampicillin (10 μg)"), diameter = c(18L, 18L, 16L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 24L, 23L, 25L, 22L, 22L, 21L, 21L, 20L, 22L, 12L, 16L, 14L, 26L, 23L, 25L, 32L, 34L, 30L, 15L, 15L, 18L, 32L, 27L, 31L), dose = c(10, 10, 10, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 30, 30, 30, 25, 25, 25, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 30, 30, 30, 25, 25, 25, 10, 10, 10)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L))
```

Current code:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- read.csv("disk_diffusion.csv")

data <- data %>%
  mutate(antibiotic = recode(antibiotic,
                             "Antibiotic X" = "Antibiotic X (10 \u03BCg)",
                             "Penicillin" = "Penicillin (1 IU)",
                             "Tetracycline" = "Tetracycline (30 \u03BCg)",
                             "Streptomycin" = "Streptomycin (25 \u03BCg)",
                             "Ampicillin" = "Ampicillin (10 \u03BCg)"
  ))

# Mean and standard deviation
grouped_data <- data %>%
  group_by(bacteria, antibiotic, dose) %>%
  summarise(
    mean_diameter = mean(diameter),
    std_diameter = sd(diameter)
  )

# plot
ggplot(grouped_data, aes(x = antibiotic, y = mean_diameter, fill = bacteria)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean_diameter - std_diameter, ymax = mean_diameter + std_diameter), 
                width = .2, 
                position = position_dodge(.9)) +
  labs(x = "Antibiotic",
       y = "Mean Diameter (mm)",
       fill = "Bacteria") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
        legend.text = element_text(face = "italic"))
```

Current plot

[image]

Comment: There are a few problems here. There is no control group, there is no evidence (or theoretical justification) for assuming a linear response, and the antibiotics might have different dose-response curves. There is no way to go from culture size at one specific dose to the dose-response curve that might allow you to correct for dosage. It's not even clear how useful that would be; the dosing of antibiotics in vivo has more to do with pharmacokinetics and toxicity as for weight-for-weight in-vitro efficacy. Probably best speaking to your supervisor - it's not a question for a programming website